# Input for the BufferReader

Tags: java, static-analysis

How can I determine that the input to the BufferedReader object? In other words I want to statically analyze the program to identify if the input to the BufferedReader object is a socket or a file.

For example in the code below, I want to be able to recognize that bfReader object is actually reading from the socket with port number 1024. How can I get this information statically? Is it an information that should appear in AST, Type or control flow graph of the program?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Bob {

private 
    int bobFortune = 1000;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Bob bob = new Bob();
    bob.run();
} 

public void run() throws Exception{
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1024);
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader bfReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
    int aliceFortune = Integer.valueOf(bfReader.readLine());
    if (bobFortune > aliceFortune) 
        System.out.println("Bob is richer");
    else 
        System.out.println("Alice is richer");

    bfReader.close();
    inputReader.close();
    serverSocket.close();

}

}
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: You trace back from the `InputStreamReader` to the `socket.getInputStream()` to the `Socket` to the `ServerSocket`. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP, I am new into static analysis. Yes this tracing back is what I want to do but how can I do it? Any guidance. Thanks!

Comment: okay. Looks still that I am not clear. I'll try again. I want to create a static analysis tool which can read any java source and look for objects like the bfReader above then realize that it actually traces back to ServerSocket. What is it that I should be using in my tool that would allow me to obtain a AST with this back tracing option? Thanks again.